# iOS client crashes when attempting to reply to comment

Tags: bug, ios-app

The iOS app crashes when I attempt to add a comment. There's a brief hesitation, then the app dies.

To clarify: this was not when responding to a deleted posted or deleted comment; it happens when I try to add a comment to an existing post, period. That said, it seems to be a problem with longer comment threads; I haven't had problems yet in cases where there are zero to a couple of comments.

Comment: Only a dupe if Ed's scenario is confirmed that the issue is when replying to a deleted comment. (think sometimes we're a bit quick on the draw to call dupe). Can you confirm @Ed Cottrell?

Comment: That's not the issue I experienced. This crash occurred on replying to any comment.

Comment: @EdCottrell, the confusion is entirely my fault. The steps in my post were reproducable, but misguided. If you read the answer from Arie Litovsky, it seems you're reporting the same bug. I've gone ahead and edited my question to match the answer better. So sorry for the confusion I caused.

Comment: @mhlester That does seem to be the same - thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @EdCottrell from the comments, and as I imagine you've figure out, it seems that you're reporting mhlester's issue. Can you confirm what version you are on?

Comment: I'm running 0.1.16.